# How to refactor redux-saga generator functions?

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, generator, redux-saga

I am new to redux-saga and generator functions.

As you can see from my sagas.js code, there is duplicate logic:

```js
import { put, takeEvery, takeLatest, all, call } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import { setRandomColour, SET_RANDOM_COLOUR_DELAYED } from './actions';

const delay = (ms) => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

export function* setRandomColourGeneratorLatest({ payload: { id, ms, sagaType } = {}} = {}){
  if(sagaType !== 'takeLatest') return;
  console.log("set random colour", id, ms);
  yield call(delay, ms);
  yield put(setRandomColour(id));
}
export function* setRandomColourGeneratorEvery({ payload: { id, ms, sagaType } = {}} = {}){
  if(sagaType !== 'takeEvery') return;
  console.log("set random colour", id, ms);
  yield call(delay, ms);
  yield put(setRandomColour(id));
}

export function* watchSetRandomColourLatest(){
  yield takeLatest(SET_RANDOM_COLOUR_DELAYED, setRandomColourGeneratorLatest)
}
export function* watchSetRandomColourEvery(){
  yield takeEvery(SET_RANDOM_COLOUR_DELAYED, setRandomColourGeneratorEvery)
}

export default function* rootSaga(){
  yield all([
    watchSetRandomColourLatest(),
    watchSetRandomColourEvery()
  ])
}
```

So I tried to refactor it by placing the yield call, and yield put into a single generator function, and then calling that within setRandomColourGeneratorLatest/Every but no matter what, I couldn't get the code to remain functioning. I believe this is because the yield would be dependent on the previous call of the generator function, whereas in this case there needs to be 2 separate versions of the generator function.

How can I refactor this code to reduce duplicate logic, whilst separating the yields for both takeEvery and takeLatest versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this? There's really not that much duplication in your code... I honestly would leave it how it is, because the odds are probably high that the common code between setRandomColourGeneratorLatest and setRandomColourGeneratorEvery will need differ at some point, then you will have to un-DRY your code.

```
import { put, takeEvery, takeLatest, all, call } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import { setRandomColour, SET_RANDOM_COLOUR_DELAYED } from './actions';

const delay = (ms) => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

export function* setRandomColourGeneratorLatest({ payload: { id, ms, sagaType } = {}} = {}){
  if(sagaType !== 'takeLatest') return;
  console.log("set random colour", id, ms);
  yield call(setRandomColor, ms, id);
}
export function* setRandomColourGeneratorEvery({ payload: { id, ms, sagaType } = {}} = {}){
  if(sagaType !== 'takeEvery') return;
  console.log("set random colour", id, ms);
  yield call(setRandomColor, ms, id);
}

export function* setRandomColor(ms, id){
  yield call(delay, ms);
  yield put(setRandomColour(id));
}

export function* watchSetRandomColourLatest(){
  yield takeLatest(SET_RANDOM_COLOUR_DELAYED, setRandomColourGeneratorLatest)
}
export function* watchSetRandomColourEvery(){
  yield takeEvery(SET_RANDOM_COLOUR_DELAYED, setRandomColourGeneratorEvery)
}

export default function* rootSaga(){
  yield all([
    watchSetRandomColourLatest(),
    watchSetRandomColourEvery()
  ])
}
```

Comment: yes this is what I was asking for, thanks. I'm sure it could be improved further but it's probably not necessary, this is enough.